# React Native 0.61: With autolinking, do you still need to add lines to Podfile?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I noticed that when I install native libraries in React Native 0.61, they do not add lines to my Podfile automatically, but when I run `pod install`, it seems to link the libraries anyway. Does anyone know how this works? Do I need to add lines to my Podfile anymore?

Answer (score 3):

**When you create a new project and react-native version >=60 , this line is automatically added in pod file ([AutoLinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md))**

```
# example/ios/Podfile
require_relative '../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

**This is path of script . When you add new library , no lines are added to my Podfile but you have to run "pod install" so that script file can run and install new pod files .**